# 'ngx-slider' is not a known element

Tags: javascript, angular, slider

Full error shows up in the `app.component.html` file where I try to use the component as follows:

```
<ngx-slider [(value)]="value" [options]="options"></ngx-slider>
```

The full error is:

[image]

But I've done exactly what the [guide](https://github.com/angular-slider/ngx-slider) says, and it's still not working:

I installed the library through the command line command: `npm install --save @angular-slider/ngx-slider` and it shows up in the `package.json` as:

[image]

I imported it in `app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgxSliderModule } from '@angular-slider/ngx-slider';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxSliderModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I've imported it into `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Options } from '@angular-slider/ngx-slider';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  value: number = 100;
  options: Options = {
    floor: 0,
    ceil: 200
  };
}
```

And finally added it to `app.component.html`:

```
<ngx-slider [(value)]="value" [options]="options"></ngx-slider>
```

So why is it not working?

Versions for reference:

- Node version: 14.17.1
- NPM version: 6.14.13
- Angular & Angular CLI version: 13

Comment: Just threw together a CLI 13.0.1 app and tried to repro this. Works as expected; no error. Only difference: I am using Node 14.17.5. Try reloading your IDE(?).

Answer (score 0):

can you try change the tsconfig.json of

```
"baseUrl": "./"
```

to

```
"baseUrl": "src"
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).